# Installing Ubuntu on btrfs over multiple drives

Tags: installation, partitioning, filesystem, raid, btrfs

When I installed Ubuntu 13.04, I managed to combine a couple of outdated askubuntu answers, as well as some of the btrfs documentation in order to figure out how to install Ubuntu over two SSDs using a single btrfs partition (I think /boot was on a small ext4 partition).

I want to install Ubuntu 13.10 in a similar way, using a single btrfs partition striping data over the two SSDs, but I don't feel comfortable synthesizing a method that I am sure will work with current software.

What is the best way to partition and install Ubuntu over two SSDs using btrfs, in an effectively RAID 0 way?

Answer (score 2):

- Install Ubuntu on one SSD
- Add the other SSD (or a partition of it) via `btrfs device add`
- Do [`btrfs balance start -mconvert=raid1 -dconvert=single`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Balance_Filters). This is done to regulate RAID.
  (Note that it is recommended to keep metadata in RAID1, which currently means "[two copies on different devices](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#btrfs)")

For more information:

- [Using btrfs with multiple devices](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Using_Btrfs_with_Multiple_Devices)
- [Balance filters](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Balance_Filters)

Comment: Is the balance command meant to optimize the data over both drives for optimal performance?

Comment: No, it just redistributes the (meta/)data across the devices according to the replication policy: read the linked page "Using btrfs with multiple devices" and the FAQ [What does "balance" do?](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#What_does_.22balance.22_do.3F)

Comment: Just as a note (I forgot to mention after installing), I had to make sure to add a few extra megabytes of free space at the beginning of the SSD for GRUB, otherwise it would not have enough space to install.