# Install Ubuntu on Btrfs Raid1 pool

Tags: virtualbox, raid, btrfs

I have seen the post [Installing Ubuntu on btrfs over multiple drives](https://askubuntu.com/questions/366466/installing-ubuntu-on-btrfs-over-multiple-drives), but the solution suggested there does not help me.
Before using Btrfs in a production environment I wanted to give it a try in Virtualbox.

I installed Ubuntu on a single Btrfs-formatted HDD first. In this configuration it boots just fine. But when I add a second, same-sized HDD to the pool and run balance so that I get a Raid1-pool for data and metadata, the pool becomes unbootable, showing 'BTRFS: open_ctree failed' on boot.

I have tried this multiple times but without success. So can anyone please explain to me the steps I need to perform so that I get a fresh Ubuntu installation on a Btrfs Raid1?